# Is there a utility for mapping a string with a custom pattern to a bean in a declarative manner?

Tags: java, regex, parsing, javabeans

I know that there are easy ways of binding for example an XML file to a bean. In contrast to that, I am looking for a library that allows me to specify some regex for parsing an entire file. I am thinking of something like:

```
@FileFormat("${value1};${value2};${num}")
class FileBean {

  private String value1;
  private String value2;
  private Integer num;

  // Getters and setters...

}

public List<FileBean> read(File file) {
  return SomeUtility.read(file, FileBean.class);
}

public void write(File file, List<FileBean> list) {
  SomeUtility.read(list, new File("./target"));
}
```

with a file containing data in the format of `${value1};${value2};${num}` such as:

```
foo;bar;123
bar;foo;494
```

Does somebody know if such a library that does what I suggest for `SomeUtility` exists already? I am bound to a number of third-party file formats for data exchange. Would be great if there was something sufficiently generic. (I know this resembles CSV but I am looking for something more flexible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is now: https://github.com/raphw/declarative-parser

This tool allows to define a parser declaratively by annotations.